# Delete the name of the folder that came up in the url domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, web

I'm having trouble with the domain url. When I call my website's url address in the browser, the folder name of the website comes up. I have another website too and that's fine, my other website url address does not show the folder name. I mean like this:

[this is an example of my other website and that's fine with not displaying the folder name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtJkq.jpg)

[And this url of my website that come show the folder name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpKn0.jpg)

the difference is quite noticeable instead. I want to make my website url address pure url name that I want without calling the folder name. it is the start page and I want to delete the folder name.
I have tried various scripts but it happens just blank and sometimes error.
this is the last script I tried and it still does not work and url still show the folder name. I have never been like this before.

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)\?redirect=1&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [L,R]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from 192.168.1.22

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

it's the htaccess script inside the public_html folder. And this script is in the folder id or folder of my website whose url is problematic :

```
## No directory listings
<IfModule autoindex>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed

# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

# RewriteBase
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)\?redirect=1&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [L,R]

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

It's not working at all and I'm also confused whether I put the url manipulation script correctly. Anyone can help me ??